# python 2.7 metacharacters as part of text

Tags: python

I have a string like this:
var = "blahblahblah\n\tblahblah". I want the \t and \n characters to be part of text, so when I do:
print(var) it will write out: blahblahblah\n\tblahblah on one row, without tab.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare it as a raw string by prefixing the string with an "r"

```
print(r"blahblahblah\n\tblahblah")
> blahblahblah\n\tblahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `string_escape` encoder:

```
print var.encode ('string_escape')
```